# Election nomination page, markdown icons are not visible in the mobile-web view

Tags: bug, design, editor, moderator-election, mobile-web

In the election nomination page, the markdown toolbar icons are not visible in the **mobile-web** view.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Markdown toolbar icons are not visible]